# Ajax Blob URL as Audio source

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to retrieve audio data via and Ajax request and load it into an audio element, but for some reason I can't get the player to work. The play button stays as disabled, seemingly without anything loaded. Here's a simplified version of my code which demonstrates the issue.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" src="" controls></audio>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.mp3',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
                var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                $('#audio').attr('src', blobUrl);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching audio:', error);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, [jQuery's `$.ajax()` function is going to try to parse some data out of text](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/), like XML or JSON.  Your MP3 is binary.  String processing on this binary data will wreck it.

Since you're making a GET request anyway, you shouldn't even use AJAX.  Just set the URL to the `src`.

```js
document.querySelector('#audio').src = 'test.mp3';
```